# R histogram from frequency table

Tags: r

So I've figured out how to drill my data down to a frequency table -

```
        Overall.Cond Freq
235            1    0
236            2    0
237            3    1
238            4    1
239            5    9
240            6    1
241            7    1
242            8    1
243            9    1
```

I want to plot a histogram from this, but when I do hist(dataFrameName) I get this error

```
Error in hist.default(veenker) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Why is that happening and how do I get around it?

EDIT: For those suggesting `barplot` as a solution (which is not the question), please consider this example of why `barplot` would not be a good solution.

This sample data

```
dt = data.frame(vals = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.0, 3.4, 26, 35, 45),
                freq = c(  2,   3,   4,   3,   2, 15, 17, 14))
```

Using `barplot(dt$freq, names.arg = dt$vals)` would produce this very misleading barplot:
[image]

However, converting the data to a vector format would make much more sense using this code `hist(as.vector(rep(dt$val, dt$freq)))`:
[image]

Comment: `hist` accepts the "raw" data and works out the contingency table for you. Instead of drilling down your data to a frequency table, just use `hist` on the (column of) data you wish to view.

Comment: It's quite surprising that there is not more discussion on this topic.  For very large frequency tables it would be easy to run out of physical memory when trying to convert the frequency table to a vector. Imagine plotting 5 samples of approximately Avogadro's number.

Answer (score 13):

Do you really want a histogram or a bar chart? If you insist on a histogram, you are lacking the upper boundary of your topmost bin; I will assume it is 10.

The solution provided by user2030503 is somewhat wasteful, as it re-creates the data set from the frequency table. Since you already have your frequency table computed, you can use it directly in construction of your histogram object. The latter is essentially a list in R.

```
Overall.Cond <- 1:10
Freq <- c(0,0,1,1,9,1,1,1,1)
myhist <-list(breaks=Overall.Cond, counts=Freq, density=Freq/diff(Overall.Cond),
              xname="Overall Cond")
class(myhist) <- "histogram"
plot(myhist)
```

As the bin width is 1, calculation of density could be simplified in this case; I just put it for the sake of generality.

Comment: OP said they wanted a histogram not a barplot (which is also what I wanted when searching for this answer).

Answer (score 3):

Rebuild your data frame:

```
df= as.data.frame(cbind(Overall.Cond= 1:9, Freq= c(0,0,1,1,9,1,1,1,1)))
df
```

Result:

```
  Overall.Cond Freq
1            1    0
2            2    0
3            3    1
4            4    1
5            5    9
6            6    1
7            7    1
8            8    1
9            9    1
```

Then make a vector of observations and plot it:

```
df.freq= as.vector(rep(df$Overall.Cond, df$Freq))
hist(df.freq)
```

[image]

Comment: I think a barplot is still better because the numbers will be centered under the bars.

Comment: This is the best answer because in most cases you want to use `hist` to build your bins.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
myfreq=table(df$columnofinterest)
plot(myfreq)
```

Comment: kind of works but draws lines instead of bars.  `barplot` works better

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be a barplot, like so:

`barplot(dt$Freq, names.arg = dt$Overall.Cond)`